# Cell culture media L-Glut dilution?

Tags: growth-media

Cross-posted on r/labrats.

I haven't done cell or tissue culture in about 4 years.

Protocol:

Volume: 200ml media (academia so using sparingly, not the whole 500ml bottle!)

1% L-Glut (250uM)

My L-Glut comes in a 100ml bottle of 200mM.

What should I make up a stock dilution of 250uM in? Distilled H2O? PBS?

Should I then add 2ml (1%) to my media? Or should I add 250uM of L-Glut directly to the media?